# Multiple checkboxes updation

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update multiple check boxes in DB.I want to update the email notification based on selected type from table mod_emailnotification_type.I already inserted it like that

```
$optionArray = $_POST['notification_type'];
$count=count($optionArray);
    foreach($optionArray as $option) {
    $notification_type =$option;
    $query="INSERT INTO mod_emailnotification_type(notification_type,user_id)VALUES('$notification_type',$user_id)";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
}
```

where notification_type are the selected checkboxes.

I have the following DB Structure

1. id(Auto Generated)
2. user_id
3. notification_type

User table have one to many relation with this table mod_emailnotification_type.

This is the result

```
id  user_id     notification_type   
1   14          general
3   14          hint
```

And I am retrieving and displaying like that in my tpl file

```
{php}
$query1="SELECT * from mod_emailnotification_type";
$result1=mysql_query($query1);
 $check=array();
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
$notification_type=$data['notification_type'];
$notification_id=$data['id'];

         $check[]=$notification_type;
        $check[$notification_type]=$data['id'];
    }
print_r($check);

{/php}
<div>
    <h1 class="email_notification">Email Notification Type</h1>
    <form action="index.php?m=networkstatus" method="post">
        {php} if(in_array("failure", $check)){
         echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="failure" checked>Failure<br>'; 
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'" >'; 

        }
        else
         echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="failure" >Failure<br>';

    if(in_array("hint", $check)){
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="hint" checked>Hint<br>';  
              echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'" >'; 

    }
    else
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="hint" >Hint<br>';

     if(in_array("maintenance", $check)){
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="maintenance" checked>Maintenance<br>';  
              echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'" >'; 

    }
    else
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="maintenance" >Maintenance<br>';

     if(in_array("system", $check)){
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="system" checked>System<br>'; 
              echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'" >'; 

    }
    else
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="system" >System<br>';

     if(in_array("general", $check)){
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="general" checked>General<br>'; 
              echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'" >'; 

    }
    else
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="general" >General<br>';

     if(in_array("security", $check)){
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="security" checked>Security<br>'; 
              echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'" >'; 

    }
    else
     echo '<input class="notification_type" type="checkbox" name="notification_type[]" value="security" >Security<br>';

if($check){
         echo '<input class="btn btn-primary submit_notif" type="submit" value="Update" name="update">';   
        }
        else
         echo '<input class="btn btn-primary submit_notif" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">';

        {/php}

    </form>
```

Comment: What's the result of your current code?

Comment: Looks like it's functioning properly. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have to update the checkboxes either checked new or unchecked old one
I have edited for you

Comment: On which condition i have to update either checked a new item or unchecked an old item